# Get size of a directory on a disk in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14, boost-filesystem

Following is a code snippet I used to get directory size in c++:

```
  boost::system::error_code ec;
  boost::filesystem::space_info si =
    boost::filesystem::space(path, ec);
  if (ec.value() == 0) {
    cout << si.capacity - si.available;
  }
```

But the above snippet seems to be giving the entire disk size instead of a particular directory size on a disk since I passed 2 different directory paths to above but both of them gave the same answer. Can someone help me with finding what's wrong with this or give me another alternative for getting the directory size in c++? TIA!

Comment: according to your argumentation addition is broken because `1+3` and `2+2` yield the same result. Please try to explain whats actually wrong

Comment: You are a aware that `boost::filesystem::space` is for disk size? Please read the manual and check if your assumptions are correct.

Comment: `boost::filesystem::space` gives information about the partition containing a path.

Comment: Edited the question now. I need to find the size of a particular directory on a disk.

Comment: What does "TIA" mean?

Answer (score 4):

[Boost Reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#space) states:

> The value of the `space_info` object is determined as if by using ISO/IEC 9945 `statvfs()` to obtain an ISO/IEC 9945 `struct statvfs`.

[Opengroup Reference](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/statvfs.html) states:

> The `statvfs()` function shall obtain information about the file system **containing** the file named by path.

[man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/statvfs.3.html) states:

> The function `statvfs()` returns information about a mounted filesystem.  `path` is the pathname of **any** file within the mounted filesystem.

**Based on your comment:**

Have a look at the example of [std::filesystem::directory_entry::file_size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry/file_size)
Or better: [Overview of Filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

If its still not clear:

- iterate over a directory
- if the entry is of your interest, add the size to the total amount
- if entry is another directory, recursively enumerate the size (hint: [std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator))

Comment: statsfs seems to be returning the entire disk space. I want something that gives me the size of a directory alone. Can you please help me with this.